# how do I make div's look the same no matter what monitor its on?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having problems figuring out how to make two divs not stack on top of each other when I'm on my laptop. it looks normal when I'm on my desktop.

I tried to make the `div`s width smaller hopefully making it not big enough to stack when I switch monitors but that didn't work.

```css
body {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

div {
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1.5px;
}

.outer {
  height: 850px;
  width: 225px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 75px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.mid {
  width: 200px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-left: 12.5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.body-model {
  height: 850px;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script href="index.js"></script>
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="mid">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body-model">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the combined width is greater than what is available? Maybe you want to look at using percentages, view port widths, flexbox, or grid layout.

Comment: There are a large variety of approaches you can take to do this, the above comment lists some but to that I would add media queries and CSS rules tailored to the purpose of your markup and the meaning of your content.

Answer (score 2):

Im not exactly sure which of the divs you're talking about, but the general approach is to use relative instead of static units.

**Your approach**

In the example you provided you mostly use px as a unit, this is static because the size of the pixel is a fixed unit no matter of the device you are using

**What you should do instead**

Try to use relative units like %, vw (viewport width) or vh (viewport height). These values will scale based on the maximum window size and stay proprotional to that maximum size.

So try switching up your units to relative values

For reference you can look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_units.asp)

If you want to stop the general overlapping of the content different approaches may be advisable like

1. a margin on one of the divs
2. a div that serves as a gap between the two divs (general not the best approach, only use in case there are no other ways)
3. or a parent container with certain css properties

If you want the behavior of each container to change based off a certain size of the window you may use mediaqueries

```
@media (max-width: 1250px) {
  /* … */
}
```

Further instruction on mediaqueries [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries?retiredLocale=de)

Answer (score 0):

In this example I did what I would do in this situation, but in reality there are multiple ways of doing this, `display: grid` being one of them.
What I did is change the `wrapper` (could be a `div`, not necessarily the `body`) `display` to `flex`, by default the `flex-direction: column`, making them go side-by-side.
And then I proceeded by setting the `.outer` class to be a fixed `width`, since this looks like a sidebar (if it's not you can tweak with it), and then on `.body-model` I changed the `width` to `100%`. I did remove the `margin-*` from each `class` since if the idea was centering the whole thing, `display: flex` or `display: grid` should be used instead.
PS: If this is a `layout` of sorts, I would recommend changing the `.wrapper` `height` to `100vh`, and changing each child `height` to `100%`.

```css
body {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}

div {
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1.5px;
}

.outer {
  height: 850px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.mid {
  height: 75px;
  margin: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.body-model {
  height: 850px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script href="index.js"></script>
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body class='wrapper'>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="mid">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body-model">

  </div>
</body>





</body>

</html>
```